# ng-Option multi [value]

Tags: angular, angular8

I have a little problem with ng-options, how to combine multiple values ​​in one ng-option value,

I tried two ways, but both have the same error.

these are the two codes that I tried :

```
<ng-option *ngFor="let farmer of listFarmer | keyvalue"
            value="{{farmer.value.id_card_number}}&kavling_number={{&kavling_number=}}"></ng-option>
```

and

```
<ng-option [value]="farmer.value.id_card_number +' '+ &kavling_number= +' '+ &kavling_number="
            *ngFor="let farmer of listFarmer | keyvalue">
            {{ farmer.value.farmer_name | titlecase }} | {{farmer.value.kavling_number }}
          </ng-option>
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: _Parser Error: Unexpected token & at column 35 in [farmer.value.id_card_number +' '+ &kavling_number= +' '+ farmer.value.kavling_number] in ng:///AppModule/PlasmaDataInputDocumentCompletenessComponent.html@159:25 ("ed"
              (change)="onSelectfarmer($event)" (clear)="onClear()">
              <ng-option [ERROR ->][value]="farmer.value.id_card_number +' '+ &kavling_number= +' '+ farmer.value.kavling_number"
     "): ng:///AppModule/PlasmaDataInputDocumentCompletenessComponent.html@159:25_

Comment: Your `kavling_number` should equal your variable. `&kavling_number={{farmer.value.kavling_number}}`. In your case you get `&kavling_number=&kavling_number=`

Comment: @Jayme , i already change but this error appears

_Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 0 in_

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure how your output should look like, but it should work like this:

```
<ng-option *ngFor="let farmer of listFarmer | keyvalue" [value]="farmer.value.id_card_number + 'someOtherValue'"></ng-option>
```

use the [] brackets for value, concat string fragments with +